# Remove Menu Item Alias and Category Alias from single article url

Tags: joomla, seo, joomla3.0, joomla-sef-urls

Hi and thanks for reading my problem.

I need to remove from single article view URL path, the Menu item Alias and Category Alias.

I needed to be like that www.joomlasite.com/id-article-alias

I don't know how, but is allready working like i want for 1 menu item articles. check these articles here in this menu item http://www.techvalue.net/parousiaseis  .  Looks like it's a bug.

Anyway, just need to remove All alias from signle article view URLs except article alias.

I am using joomla 3.2.3
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Joomla SEF always follows its standards and includes as much menu items as you have. For example, article Test Article in category Test Category, which have a menu link Test Article Menu, will have a SEF link like this:

yoursite.com/test-article-menu

If you add menu item for category, link will look like this:

yoursite.com/test-cateory-menu/test-article-menu

Not, that only menu items aliases count in this case, not article/category aliases.

If you want more flexibility, you should use 3rd party SEO extensions like sh404SEF or JoomSEF. Or you may write your own router, if you have an experience.

Comment: "Or you may write your own router" - are you talking about component router or some global router?

Comment: Component's router, yes.

Comment: I don't seem to have access to the 'test-article-menu' (the menu alias) part of the URL in the component router. I have access to the part build/parsed by the component's router. Am I missing something here?